# C#: Pushing changes from DataGridView to BindingList back to database?

Tags: database, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I'm using a BindingList to display a list of Person objects in a DataGridView in a Windows Forms application.  Changes to the DataGridView change the underlying BindingList.  I've got this part working.

Now I want the list persisted to a database table.  Reading the list from the database and populating the Person list is straight forward, but if I add/edit/delete a person from the DataGridView, how and when do I persist that change back to the database?

(Secondly, is this approach okay or am I missing some bigger picture?  I don't want to use data tables because I want to work with my code in an abstracted object oriented way.)

Answer (score 1):

For easy persistence of objects in Windows Forms for a start you can use [LINQ2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), it does exactly what you want plus also materializes objects when you want to gather them from database.

Quick example, after you create linq context from database schema for supported databases, which is SQL Server (Express), all you need is to create it's instance in your form and use it during single atomic operation with data - read, edit, write or cancel.

```
  private YourAppContext context;

  private void RenewContext()
  {
     context = new YourAppContext();
  }

  private void LoadData()
  {
    RenewContext();
    DataGridView1.DataSource = context.Articles.OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePosted).Take(10);
  }

  private void AcceptButtonPressed()
  {
    context.SubmitChanges();
  }

  private void CancelButtonPressed()
  {
    LoadData();
  }
```

Obviously you can pass your data through BindingSource.

Comment: Funny I've used Linq2Sql in ASP.NET before but using here totally escaped me.  Thanks for pointing that out!  This might be the way I decide to go although I'm still curious how to do it without using linq2sql.

Comment: Then you should probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your objects by yourself, keep track of changed properties (and maintain a list of new and deleted objcts) and reverse the logic of gathering data to be able to call INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements according to your changes. In some of this tasks reflection and attributing might be of use, so you will be able to store objects without writing a query by yourself but automatically generating queries instead. Yet why would you want to reimplement the wheel ?

Comment: Good point.  A practical reason I just discovered is that since I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express I don't think the Linq to SQL designer is supported against a sql server database.